# Check if a method of a class is called from the method of the different class in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Let's say there are two classes:

1.

```rb
class Fax
  def initialize(number)
    **code**
  end

  def send!
    **code**
  end
end
```

2. 

```rb
class FaxJob
  def perform
    Fax.new(number).send!
  end
end
```

In the FaxJobSpec, I need to confirm that
`FaxJob.perform_now(number)` run the `Fax.new(number).send!`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `double`.

```rb
it 'sends fax!' do
  fax_instance = instance_double(Fax)
  allow(Fax).to(receive(:new).and_return(fax_instance))
  allow(fax_instance).to(receive(:send!))

  FaxJob.perform_now(number)

  expect(fax_instance).to(have_received(:send!))
end
```

You can avoid having to `allow` instance and class with a minor refactor to your `Fax` class:

```rb
class Fax
  def self.send!(number)
    new(number).send!
  end
end
```

`FaxJob`:

```rb
class FaxJob
  def perform
    Fax.send!(number)
  end
end
```

And then your test:

```rb
it 'sends fax!' do
  allow(Fax).to(receive(:send!).and_call_original)

  FaxJob.perform_now(number)

  expect(Fax).to(have_received(:send!).with(number))
end
```

If you are really into DRY, this should work too:

```rb
it 'sends fax!' do
  expect(Fax).to(receive(:send!).with(number))

  FaxJob.perform_now(number)
end
```

I am not really found of this latter one because it does not respect the AAA (arrange, act, assert) and it compromises readability, imo.

Comment: Getting =>
`#<InstanceDouble(Fax) (anonymous)> is a pure test double. "and_call_original" is only available on a partial double.`

Comment: Sorry, mate, my fault. Just updated the answer. But you can remove the `.and_call_original`.